# How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate swagger documentation\UI for a webapi2 project.  Our models are shared with some legacy interfaces so there are a couple of properties I want to ignore on the models.  I can't use JsonIgnore attribute because the legacy interfaces also need to serialize to JSON so I don't want to ignore the properties globally, just in the Swashbuckle configuration.

I found a method of doing this documented here:

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/73

But this appears to be out of date with the current Swashbuckle release.

The method recommended for the old version of Swashbuckle is using an IModelFilter implementation as follows:

```
public class OmitIgnoredProperties : IModelFilter
{
    public void Apply(DataType model, DataTypeRegistry dataTypeRegistry, Type type)
    {
        var ignoredProperties = … // use reflection to find any properties on 
                                  // type decorated with the ignore attributes

        foreach (var prop in ignoredProperties) 
            model.Properties.Remove(prop.Name);

    }
}

SwaggerSpecConfig.Customize(c => c.ModelFilter<OmitIgnoredProperties>());
```

But I'm unsure how to configure Swashbuckle to use the IModelFilter in the current version?  I'm using Swashbuckle 5.5.3.

Comment: you can actually use JsonIgnore propety which will not show up the property in the swagger

Comment: As mentioned in the question I don't want to use JsonIgnore as I have legacy code that also needs to use the models, and if I apply JsonIgnore that will affect swagger and the legacy code...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you need to do this but without using JsonIgnore (maybe you still need to serialize/deserialize the property) then just create a custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Then a schema filter similar to [Johng's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466059/2020093)

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    #region ISchemaFilter Members

    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        if (schema?.properties == null || type == null)
            return;

        var excludedProperties = type.GetProperties()
                                     .Where(t => 
                                            t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() 
                                            != null);

        foreach (var excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
        {
            if (schema.properties.ContainsKey(excludedProperty.Name))
                schema.properties.Remove(excludedProperty.Name);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Don't forget to register the filter

```
c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();
```

Comment: It seems this does only work for output models ? When I apply this code on an input model (used by GET), that model is not found?

Comment: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaFilter  does not have a type parameter. How to solve it there?

Comment: I posted an edit that makes it work on the latest dotnetcore.

Comment: I've ran into an issue using this solution with case sensitivity. My property names in my POCOs were in PascalCase while the serialized object's name was in camelCase, so instead of ContainsKey, may be a good idea to check for  var foundKey = schema.properties.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x, excludedProperty.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

Comment: @Richard This is an extremely useful answer. I have posted an updated version of it [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480742/795690) which: works on the latest (v5) version of Swashbuckle; can be applied to fields as well as properties; respects the possible renaming of data members by the `JsonProperty` attribute. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the guideline, had a issue with obsolete attribute not working, did get a working solution with branding up properties and methods with depricated thanks to you, https://gist.github.com/martea/7f5210222076cedc371988ee1d123c11

Comment: @Richard i tried this solution on asp.net core 3.1 it seems custom attribute, not picking `ar excludedProperties = context.Type.GetProperties()
                .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SwaggerExcludeAttribute), true) != null);` line always empty, any thought?

Comment: Doesn't work for me with SubClass, polymorphism and JsonIgnore attribute on override field of the subclass, any ideas for .NET 6 ?

Answer (score 73):

Solution for **.NET Core 3.1** and **.NET Standard 2.1**:

Use `JsonIgnore` from `System.Text.Json.Serialization` namespace.

( `JsonIgnore` from `Newtonsoft.Json` will NOT work )

```
public class Test
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public int HiddenProperty { get; set; }
    public int VisibleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: For anyone trying this with Newtonsoft, you might need to install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` nuget.

Comment: Not found even after installing the nuget... .NET 6

Comment: Wow!, that's the 100% correct answer. I was trying to figure out this since last 2 hours.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with SubClass, polymorphism and JsonIgnore attribute on override field of the subclass, any ideas for .NET 6 ?

Comment: I'm on .NET 7 and this simply does nothing. Yes I triple checked that I didn't have the Newtonsoft `using`. Making the field `internal` was the way to go.

Answer (score 61):

If you mark field/property as `internal` or `protected` or `private`, it will be ignored automatically by swashbuckle in swagger documentation.
Update: Obviously, those properties/fields won't be populated in request/response.

Comment: This is the nicest solution IMO

Comment: This would prevent the property from getting populated from the request body json

Comment: That is true, however this works great for internal state stuff or other properties that might not be needed in the original request. Not saying this is a perfect architecture, but it's an option.

Answer (score 39):

The code below is very much based on @Richard's answer, but I am including it as a new answer because it has three completely new, useful features which I have added:

- Runs on .NET Core on the latest version of Swashbuckle (v5)
- Allows the `SwaggerIgnore` attribute to be applied to fields not just to properties
- Handles the fact that property and field names may have been overridden using the `JsonProperty` attribute
- EDIT: Now correctly handles camelCasing of originally TitleCased fields or properties (prompted by @mattruma's answer)

So the revised code is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SwaggerIgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

```
internal static class StringExtensions
{
    internal static string ToCamelCase(this string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
        return char.ToLowerInvariant(value[0]) + value.Substring(1);
    }
}
```

```
public class SwaggerIgnoreFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext schemaFilterContext)
    {
        if (schema.Properties.Count == 0)
            return;

        const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                          BindingFlags.Instance;
        var memberList = schemaFilterContext.SystemType // In v5.3.3+ use Type instead
                            .GetFields(bindingFlags).Cast<MemberInfo>()
                            .Concat(schemaFilterContext.SystemType // In v5.3.3+ use Type instead
                            .GetProperties(bindingFlags));

        var excludedList = memberList.Where(m =>
                                            m.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerIgnoreAttribute>()
                                            != null)
                                     .Select(m =>
                                         (m.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()
                                          ?.PropertyName
                                          ?? m.Name.ToCamelCase()));

        foreach (var excludedName in excludedList)
        {
            if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(excludedName))
                schema.Properties.Remove(excludedName);
        }
    }
}
```

and in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerIgnoreFilter>();
    ...
});
```

Comment: @mattruma was right about camel casing. I've extracted the internal method used by Swashbuckle and used that. I'm not sure how to read the current settings of Swashbuckle in the context of this filter, as I think the camel casing can be switched on or off somewhere.

Comment: As per several other answers above, I think the difference in required classes for this version vs. @Richard's version is to do with .NET Core vs. Framework, not Swagger v5 vs. v4. If someone needed to, it would be relatively easy to convert the other features of this version back to the .NET Framework classes.

Comment: I'm using Nswag instead of Swashbuckle. Would anyone know if there is any match for the "ISchemaFilter" interface in Nswag?

Comment: schemaFilterContext.SystemType does not exist on lib v5.3.3

Comment: "schemaFilterContext.SystemType does not exist on lib v5.3.3" - use schemaFilterContext.Type instead.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with SubClass, polymorphism and JsonIgnore attribute on override field of the subclass, any ideas for .NET 6 ?

Comment: cannot find `?.PropertyName` :(

Comment: fixed the missing prop but still not hiding from tryout params

Answer (score 16):

The `AspNetCore` solution looks like:

```
public class SwaggerExcludeSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var excludedProperties = context.SystemType.GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
        {
            if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(excludedProperty.Name))
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(excludedProperty.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, but I am using AspNetCore 2, wonder if that makes a difference?

Comment: This didn't work for me because my schema is Pascal casing, but the context appears to be using camel case.

Comment: Have updated [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480742/795690) to work with latest (v5) version of Swashbuckle, also to deal with fields, also to deal with field/property renames using the `JsonProperty` attribute.

Answer (score 13):

Well, with a bit of poking I found a way to do this using ISchemaFilter:

```
public class ApplyCustomSchemaFilters : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        var excludeProperties = new[] {"myProp1", "myProp2"};

        foreach(var prop in excludeProperties)
            if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(prop))
                schema.Properties.Remove(prop);
    }
}
```

then when calling `httpConfiguration.EnableSwagger` I set the `SwaggerDocsConfig` to use this SchemaFilter as follows:

```
c.SchemaFilter<ApplyCustomSchemaFilters>();
```

Hope this helps someone.  I'd still be curious on whether it's possible to use the IModelFilter somehow though.

Answer (score 13):

For people like me who are using **.Net** Core and are using the build in `app.UseSwaggerUi3WithApiExplorer()`

Use `[JsonIgnore]` tag using **Newtonsoft.Json**;

```
public class Project
{
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SomeValueYouWantToIgnore { get; set; }
}
```

It will be excluded from your documentation.

Comment: Does this still allow the ignored property to be serialized and deserialized though as OP asked for?

Comment: i'm using .net core 3.1, and [JsonIgnore] from System.Text.Json.Serialization works, but from Newtonsoft.Json doesn't!

Comment: For anyone trying this with Newtonsoft, you might need to install the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` nuget.

Answer (score 11):

I have here a working example with DotNetCore 3 and Swashbuckle 5. It took me a few hours to get it in place so I thought to come back to this thread which helped me but didn't solve my issue.

Create a dummy custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Create a SchemaFilter which will be used by swagger to generate the API Model Schema

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.ApiModel is ApiObject))
        {
            return;
        }

        var model = context.ApiModel as ApiObject;

        if (schema?.Properties == null || model?.ApiProperties == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var excludedProperties = model.Type
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(
                    t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null
                );

        var excludedSchemaProperties = model.ApiProperties
               .Where(
                    ap => excludedProperties.Any(
                        pi => pi.Name == ap.MemberInfo.Name
                    )
                );

        foreach (var propertyToExclude in excludedSchemaProperties)
        {
            schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToExclude.ApiName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, inside the `Startup.cs` file add this to the swagger configuration

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();
});
```

You can now use the custom attribute on a property that you want to exclude from the API Mode Shema like this

```
public class MyApiModel
{
    [SwaggerExclude]
    public Guid Token { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` package, it allows you to mark that some properties are only displayed in the input parameters, and some are only displayed in the output.

for example, if you want to hide the `AlertId` in the input parameter of the post, you just need to do this by the `[SwaggerSchema]`:

```cs
public class Alert
{
    [SwaggerSchema(ReadOnly = true)]
    public string AlertId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

See more about it in the [Documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckleaspnetcoreannotations)

Comment: This is working quit nice for primary keys where you want to hide them when creating items, but only list them when retrieving.

Answer (score 8):

[Based on Stef Heyenrath's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49093716/1768)

Attribute to mark properties to exclude from the Swagger documentation.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

The filter to exclude the properties from the Swagger documentation.

```
public class SwaggerExcludeSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var excludedProperties = 
            context.SystemType.GetProperties().Where(
                t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
        {
            var propertyToRemove =
                schema.Properties.Keys.SingleOrDefault(
                    x => x.ToLower() == excludedProperty.Name.ToLower());

            if (propertyToRemove != null)
            {
                schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToRemove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `schema.Properties.Keys` are `camelCase`, while the properties themselves are `PascalCase`. Tweaked the method to convert both to lower case and compare to see what should be excluded.

Comment: I've done a version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480742/795690) which takes on board your good point about camel casing (thank you!), but does it using the `ToCamelCase` method copied from Swashbuckle, and also supports excluding fields as well as properties, and also the possibility of property renaming using `JsonProperty`.

Comment: I avoided the property naming issues by having the constructor of my SchemaFilter take an instance of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISerializerDataContractResolver`, store it as a member variable, and then use that to lookup the type's serialized property names by correlating on MemberInfos. This way, it doesn't matter what serializer you use or whether your members are renamed.

Answer (score 7):

Swashbuckle now has support for Newtonsoft.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

```
dotnet add package --version 5.3.1 Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft

`services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport(); // explicit opt-in - needs tobe placed after AddSwaggerGen();`
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an older question, but an low-effort, intermediate solution has since become available in Swashbuckle.

Hiding legacy properties from documentation doesn't do much to discourage usage of these properties - it just delays *discovery*. After all, they're still part of the model. In fact, leaving them undocumented means consumers have no way of knowing they shouldn't use them!

Rather than have them go undocumented, you should simply consider marking them `[Obsolete]`.

Swashbuckle will then mark them as deprecated in the swagger.json. In the UI, this will hide them in the Example Value sections, and in the Schema sections, they will show as grayed out with strikethrough on the names.

If you still want them to be completely hidden from the documentation, you can then set in `SwaggerGeneratorOptions.IgnoreObsoleteProperties = true`.

This was not a possible solution at the time this question was originally asked. The *deprecated* flag is a feature of OpenAPI v3, which was not released until 2017.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I used with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute:

```
internal class ApplySchemaVendorExtensions : Swashbuckle.Swagger.ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                                 .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute), true)?.Any() == true))
            if (schema?.properties?.ContainsKey(prop.Name) == true)
                schema?.properties?.Remove(prop.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193046/11748401  answer, for creating a filter you can simply use the following code:

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {

        var excludeProperties = context.ApiModel.Type?.GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(SwaggerExcludeAttribute)));
        if (excludeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var property in excludeProperties)
            {
                // Because swagger uses camel casing
                var propertyName = $"{ToLowerInvariant(property.Name[0])}{property.Name.Substring(1)}";
                if (model.Properties.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                {
                    model.Properties.Remove(propertyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

([Based on mutex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model#41006116).)

I added another line to not have problems with `NullReferenceException`.

```
public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
{
  var excludeProperties = new[] { "myProp1", "myProp2, myProp3"};

   foreach (var prop in excludeProperties)
     if(schema.properties != null) // This line
       if (schema.properties.ContainsKey(prop))
        schema.properties.Remove(prop);        
}
```

If you want to delete all schemas

```
public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
{
  schema.properties = null;       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I wanted to keep my Application Layer DTOs clean (without any annotation like JsonIngore) but still being able to use them in my Controllers Web APIs.

So, in my Application Layer I have a DTO like this:

```
public class CreateItemCommand {
     public Guid ContainerId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And my API design for creating an item is something like:
`POST /containers/{containerId}/items`

As the ContainerId is coming from the api route, I don't want the asp.net core trying to bind it into the command DTO and I don't want swashbuckle listing it neither.

So my solution is to inherit the original DTO in the API layer like this:

```
public class CreateItemCommandMod : CreateItemCommand {
   #pragma warning disable IDE0051
   private new ContainerID { get; }
   #pragma warning restore IDE0051
}

...

[HttpPost("{containerId}/items}")]
public Task Create(
   [FromRoute] Guid containerId,
   [FromBody] CreateItemCommandMod command,
) => useCase.Create(command.Apply(r => r.ContainerId = containerId));
```

- The useCase.Create from the ApplicationLayer expects the base class CreateItemCommand.
- .Apply is just a very simple extension method that i've made to easily set the routing parameter value into the correspondent dto property.

Answer (score 3):

Very userful solution form @Jay Shah, but if you using N'Tier architecture you can not reach protected or private DAL data from BL. to solve this, you can make this prop's acces modifier as "protected internal"

```
public class Test
{
    
    protected internal int HiddenProperty { get; set; }
    
}
```

with this you can access aforementioned data from BL but not PL. or API layer.

Comment: simple solutions is the best solutions; tanx @hgrbz

Answer (score 2):

I get inspired by the blog of [Ignoring properties from controller action model in Swagger using JsonIgnore](https://www.dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/october/ignoring-properties-from-controller-action-model-in-swagger-using-jsonignore/).

I'm using `.net core 2.1` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.3.1`.
The code below solved the problem.

**Add a new filter**

```java
public class SwaggerJsonIgnoreFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var ignoredProperties = context.MethodInfo.GetParameters()
                .SelectMany(p => p.ParameterType.GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => prop.GetCustomAttribute<JsonIgnoreAttribute>() != null))
                .ToList();

            if (!ignoredProperties.Any()) return;

            foreach (var property in ignoredProperties)
            {
                operation.Parameters = operation.Parameters
                    .Where(p => (!p.Name.Equals(property.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))
                    .ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Use the Filter in Startup.cs**

```java
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

......

    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "CustomApi", Version = "v1" });
        options.OperationFilter<SwaggerJsonIgnoreFilter>();
    });

......

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed more control to remove properties which were declared elsewhere and couldn't easly use a removal attribute.

The filter created removed all items which it came accross from my `excludes` list:

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private static readonly List<string> excludes = new List<string>()
    {
       "StoredProcedureName", "ValidationErrors", "changeTracker",
       "code", "customerId", "IsDebug",
    };

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null || context == null)
            return;

        // Find all properties by name which need to be removed 
       // and not shown on the swagger spec.
        schema.Properties
              .Where(prp => excludes.Any(exc => string.Equals(exc, prp.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
              .Select(prExclude => prExclude.Key)
              .ToList()
              .ForEach(key => schema.Properties.Remove(key));    
     }
 }
```

In startup or program.cs for you .Net 6 fans.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
                    {
                        Version = "2.5",
                        Title = "My Swagger Doc G",
                    });

                    c.SchemaFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();     
                    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using dotnet core 3.1 and Swashbuckle 6.3.1, here is updated version with the similar logic for using `ISchemaFilter` to filter properties marked with customed attribute `SwaggerExcludeAttribute`

```cs
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.Type;
        if (!schema.Properties.Any() || type == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var excludedPropertyNames = type
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(
                    t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() != null
                ).Select(d => d.Name).ToList();

        if (!excludedPropertyNames.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var excludedSchemaPropertyKey = schema.Properties
               .Where(
                    ap => excludedPropertyNames.Any(
                        pn => pn.ToLower() == ap.Key
                    )
                ).Select(ap => ap.Key);

        foreach (var propertyToExclude in excludedSchemaPropertyKey)
        {
            schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToExclude);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works except for the "pn => pn.ToLower() == ap.Key" line... This should probably be "pn => pn.ToLower() == ap.Key.ToLower()"

Answer (score 1):

Attribute to enable annotation of properties.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Filter to exclude all properties annotated with attribute.

```
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema.Properties is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var property in context.Type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>() is {}))
        {
            var remove = schema.Properties.Keys.SingleOrDefault(p => p == property.Name);

            if (remove is {})
            {
                _ = schema.Properties.Remove(remove);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Filter registration in Swagger generation service.

```
_ = services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.SchemaFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>());
```

Annotation on properties that should be excluded.

```
public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [SwaggerExclude]
    public string? StackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter created removed all items which it came accross from my excludes list.

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
namespace Api.Helpers
{
public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (operation.Parameters.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var ignoredProperties = new[] { "CacheKey", "CacheTimeSeconds" };
        foreach (var property in ignoredProperties)
        {
            operation.Parameters = operation.Parameters
                .Where(p => (!p.Name.Equals(property, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

}

In startup or program.cs for you .Net 8.0

```
 c.OperationFilter<SwaggerExcludeFilter>();
```