# Swashbuckle - Handling Jsonignore so model properties do not show

Tags: json.net, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I am currently using Swashbuckle NET CORE with an ASPNET Core project and can't get the Jsonignore property on my ApiModels to be ignored from swagger.

I have a situation when some of the properties such as a Stream are being put on the swagger UI documentation with values such as FileStream.CanRead FileStream.CanWrite.  This properties aren't set via swagger as they are part of the Stream object used when a file is uploaded.

Hence I want to be able to ignore this whole property from being shown in swagger.

I have tried decorating with [JsonIgnore] but this doesn't seem to work. I have also added code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model) but that hasn't worked either.

Can provide more info as required