# How can I tell Swagger to not show certain fields in my input class as parameters?

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an api app where the controller method takes a class as input.  I'm using Swagger to show the user what variables are in that class.  I used the class for other purposes so for certain methods I'd like Swagger not to show certain objects.  I tried the attribute [IgnoreDataMember] mentioned [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API), but it didn't seem to do anything.  How can I prevent Swagger from showing every object in the input class?

So here is the method definition:

```
[HttpPost("Receive")]
[Produces("application/json", Type = typeof(APIResponse))]
public APIResponse Receive(MyClass item)
{....}
```

MyClass is defined with 4 objects:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int itemID { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public int vendor_id { get; set; }
    public string ship_name { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, Swagger shows all 4 objects as parameters:

[image]

For this method, I'd like to only show 2 of the 4 class objects as parameters.  For other methods, I'll need to show all 4.  Is there a way to do this or will I need to create a class for each method?

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model/46237000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Swagger` is not prepared to do that, in case you want to have a parameter, you can add a default value like

`public void myMethod(string a = "abc", int a = 1)`

But, if you want to omit completely a parameter, you can do a hack like this:

Add a new file with the name **CustomSchemaFilters**

```
public class CustomSchemaFilters : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        var excludeProperties = new[] {"name", "lastname, "token"};

        foreach(var prop in excludeProperties)
            if (schema.properties.ContainsKey(prop))
                schema.properties.Remove(prop);
    }
}
```

and in your file **AppStart/SwaggerConfig.cs**

And add in the same file, this line

`c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());`

just inside of:

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    { ...`

Add the line:

`c.SchemaFilter<CustomSchemaFilters>();`

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like it would be much easier just to add a second class, which I can do in this case.  I'm going to keep your code because I could see in the future having a class I can't change where I would have to use this.