# How to exclude property in Request payload in swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have below Endpoint in `ASP.Net Core 2.1` with `EF Core 2.1`

```
  public class CustomerController
{
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]CustomerTO customer)
    {

    }

    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var customer = _dal.GetCustomer(id);
        return Ok(customer);
    }
}
```

CustomerTO looks as

```
public class CustomerTO
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    //others
}
```

Now the issue is in Swagger docs, the request payload for POST includes `CustomerId: 0` (however optional)

So the consumer of the API passes CustomerId = someInt in the POST request, as its an Identity property in EF Core Dal, it throws the error

```
Cannot insert value on Identity column...
```

This error is quite obvious & acceptable,

> what is my requirement how do I make Swagger aware that CustomerId is
>   not part of request payload in POST request?

Creating a separate DTO for Get & Post seems an overhead.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you can use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute it should work out of the box, otherwise you can find solutions in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model)

Comment: @DarjanBogdan, But I need to include the CustomerId property in Get response payload

Comment: usually that is the reason to separate input/request and output/response models :)

Answer (score 1):

For this specific scenario, you can simply make the property nullable and then decorate it as follows:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore]
public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Then, if it has a value, it will be present, otherwise it will not be part of the JSON object.

However, if you find yourself needing to change multiple different properties or adding/removing stuff for the sake of just the request or the response more than this, then @DarjanBogdan is correct: you should just use different classes for each.