# Ignore Property From Swagger UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to ignore property on swagger UI. based on this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model) I have implemented a Filter and tried

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (schema?.Properties == null || context == null) return;
        var excludedProperties = context.Type.GetProperties()
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(SwaggerExcludeAttribute), true) != null);
        foreach (var excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
        {
            if (schema.Properties.ContainsKey(excludedProperty.Name))
                schema.Properties.Remove(excludedProperty.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

1. custom attribute seems not properly getting by reflection `excludedProperties` always empty.
2. `context.MemberInfo` does read the property but cannot remove from `schema.Properties` because no properties there

my sample model is like

```
public class SequenceSetupListModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    [SwaggerExclude]
    public IList<Sequence> SequenceLists { get; set; }
}
```

What I'm missing here

Regards

Comment: How do you use this model? It is for response or request?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I'm using for request. for one of post method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need to define own attribute for request models. If you are using Json.NET then use `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: Yes i know that but i just want to know why this is not working

Comment: I'm using 5.2.1

Comment: Why do you think that your code doesn't work? `excludedProperties ` can be empty for some controllers. Just run it without debugging and see if `SequenceLists ` is still in Swagger. Your code works well in my default project

Comment: it didn't work.  it shows. I'm wondering how it works on you?

Comment: Are U sure that your code is the same as in the question? You wrote: "context.MemberInfo does read" but there is no such code. Show the screen of your model in swagger

Comment: it does anyway i gave up i'm going with JsonIgnore thanks for the answer

Comment: This means you can't send the property with a json post request

Answer (score 8):

If you mark the property as `internal` instead of public then it will be ignored by Swashbuckle.

Answer (score 4):

`[JsonIgnore]`
will just ignore property if the way of model binding is `[FromBody]`
and it does not work for `[FromQuery]`  and  `[FromForm]`
use this filter to ignore properties in all binding way

```
 public class IgnorePropertyFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ApiDescription == null || operation.Parameters == null)
            return;

        if (!context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Any())
            return;

        
        context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Where(p => p.Source.Equals(BindingSource.Form)
                    && p.CustomAttributes().Any(p => p.GetType().Equals(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))))
            .ForAll(p => operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.Single(v => v.Schema.Properties.Remove(p.Name)));



        context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Where(p => p.Source.Equals(BindingSource.Query)
                      && p.CustomAttributes().Any(p => p.GetType().Equals(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))))
            .ForAll(p => operation.Parameters.Remove(operation.Parameters.Single(w => w.Name.Equals(p.Name))));


        #region OldCode

        //var excludedProperties = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.Where(p =>
        //    p.Source.Equals(BindingSource.Form));

        //if (excludedProperties.Any())
        //{

        //    foreach (var excludedPropertie in excludedProperties)
        //    {
        //        foreach (var customAttribute in excludedPropertie.CustomAttributes())
        //        {
        //            if (customAttribute.GetType() == typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute))
        //            {
        //                for (int i = 0; i < operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.Count; i++)
        //                {
        //                    for (int j = 0; j < operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(i).Encoding.Count; j++)
        //                    {
        //                        if (operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(i).Encoding.ElementAt(j).Key ==
        //                            excludedPropertie.Name)
        //                        {
        //                            operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(i).Encoding
        //                                .Remove(operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(i).Encoding
        //                                    .ElementAt(j));
        //                            operation.RequestBody.Content.Values.ElementAt(i).Schema.Properties.Remove(excludedPropertie.Name);


        //                        }
        //                    }
        //                }

        //            }
        //        }
        //    }

        //}


        #endregion
    }
}
```

in startup

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.OperationFilter<IgnorePropertyFilter>();
});
```

now `[JsonIgnore]` will work in all model binding

Comment: .ForAll doesn't seem to exist in any documentation...

Comment: in this namespace AutoMapper.Internal or you can use foreach loop

Comment: Ah... we aren't using Automapper for some reason. I had tried ToList().ForEach() but that threw an exception so I gave up... I'll have to try it again after my vacation.

Comment: I edited the above code, you can use old code it works

Comment: Thanks! This worked out well for my use case :)

Answer (score 2):

To all who are wondering why [JsonIgnore] isn't working, its because you cannot use the Newtonsoft library version on .net core 3.x.  You need to use the System.Text.Json nuget package.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft

Comment: You can use the Newtonsoft library on .NET Core 3.x

Answer (score 2):

There is the [OpenApiIgnore] attribute in the NSwag.Annotations namespace for AspNetCore.  It appears to work on a class or a method and excludes them from the generated Swagger document.  You will need to include the NSwag.AspNetCore package from NuGet.

Comment: Is there concern in using Swashbuckle + NSwag in the same project? Is there overlap in functionality?