# How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model for a specific api version only

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I needed to add a property to a model and I have implemented what is suggested in the [selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48454933/322541) and it's working in that it removes the property I have tagged with `SwaggerIgnorePropertyAttribute` attribute of the model.
My question is , if I have several API versions of my application,how to remove it from the swagger doc/schema for certain versions? I only care not to see the added property in swagger. I only really have 1 version of the model across the application even though I have several version of the app.

I added the version like this:

```
            services.AddSwaggerGen(
                swaggerOptions =>
                {
                    swaggerOptions.SwaggerDoc(
                        "v1",
                        new Info
                        {
                            Title = "Titlebla1",
                            Description = "bla1",
                            Version = "v1"
                        });

                    swaggerOptions.SwaggerDoc(
                        "v2",
                        new Info
                        {
                            Title = "Titlebla2",
                            Description = "bla2",
                            Version = "v2"
                        });
 etc
```

I know that I can find the version by using SwaggerDocument and doing something like this: `swaggerDoc.Info.Version` but how can I get access to SwaggerDocument from the Apply in my SwaggerExcludePropertySchemaFilter  class below ?

```
private class SwaggerExcludePropertySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
        {
            public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
            {
                if (schema?.Properties == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var excludedProperties = context.SystemType.GetProperties().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerIgnorePropertyAttribute>() != null);

                foreach (var excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
                {
                    var propertyToRemove = schema.Properties.Keys.SingleOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x, excludedProperty.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

                    if (propertyToRemove != null)
                    {
                        schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToRemove);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use `IDocumentFilter` , see example:

```
 public class CustomSwaggerFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var nonRequiredMYPropertyAPIs = swaggerDoc.Paths
            .Where(x => !x.Key.ToLower().Contains("v1") /*the version you want to remove the property */)
            .ToList();
        nonRequiredMYPropertyAPIs.ForEach(x => { 
                                            swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas["YOUR_CLASS_MODEL"]
                                            .Properties.Remove("PROPERTY_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_IGNORE");
                                        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget register the filter:

```
   c.DocumentFilter<CustomSwaggerFilter>();
```

Comment: The Definition's read-only property that I want to remove isn't in paths.It's in Definitions. I guess that mean I could do this swaggerDoc.Definitions["YOUR_CLASS_MODEL"].Properties.Remove("PROPERTY_NAME_YOU_WANT_TO_IGNORE") . Right?