# ASP.NET Core: Hide a DTO property from a REST API response based on application API version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

What is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607495/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model-for-a-specific-api-vers/65659586#65659586) removes the property from the generated swagger json but what I want is to a hide the property from the response of API call (eg. GET) based on the which API version the call gets made with.
Attributes like `[JsonIgnore]` doesn't help me with my question.

Any ideas

Comment: Why don't you create another DTO for another version of API. E.g. if there is an existing `CreateUserDto` for v1 of the API add another one e.g. `CreateUserDtoV2' and use it in v2 API.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich That is what I initially did but it caused to keep changing my code everywhere(models,controllers etc) and resolve compile problems related to using v1 or v2's DTO till I reached a part of the code where I got stuck.