# Swashbuckle XML Comments with Property Hiding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Is there a way how to make Swashbuckle take the XML Comments for properties which hide those in the base class?

```cs
class Base {

  /// <summary>
  /// This comment shows in swagger UI.
  /// </summary>
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

class Model: Base {
  /// <summary>
  /// This comment is not visible in swagger UI.
  /// </summary>
  public new int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any workaround, e.g. using a kind of SchemaFilter?

**UPDATED**
The above simple example works as expected.

Our problem is probably caused by a wrong configuration of the IncludeXmlComments option as our models come from multiple assemblies.
I found a related discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi/issues/93)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model)

Comment: When I test, I see the comments for derived Model (not Base), which I understand is what you want.  Have reproduced in multiple asp.net core test apps.

Comment: As a workaround... I would suggest to to put you base class in some other dll than your model class. Then you add only the model dll to swagger
with `c.IncludeXmlComments(filePath); `

Comment: I confused myself when analyzing the code. I'll update the question.