# Entity Framework model as Request Model

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create Post API, which has following Model as request

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            EmployeeDetails = new HashSet<EmployeeDetail>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class EmployeeDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string? Details { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

and I have and Post API which accept in parameter EmployeeDetail

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(EmployeeDetail empDetail){
      

}

so for this getting error : 
Bad Request 400.
```

Code to insert empDetail,(Let assume Employee already exist in database so not binding any value with Employee object., and based on EmployeeId, inserting Employee detail in employeeDetail table.)

```
This is what swagger suggesting for body request.
{
  "id": 0,
  "employeeId": 0,
  "details": "string",
  "employee": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "gender": "string",
    "age": 0,
    "employeeDetails": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
}

//But I only want to pass 
{ 
  "id": 0,
  "employeeId": 0,
  "details": "string"
}
```

**Note : Requirement is to use only DbContext Model only.**
Any solution Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate `DTO` for your request and then fill the model from that Or if you want to use the same model you can set the Employee property as `internal` or `protected` or `private` so the swagger can ignore it.

This is applicable to `swashbuckle` Swagger

Reference for [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

[How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but requirement is to use only DbContextModel.

Comment: It is really requirement? Changing API or vice versa will force changing database model. Do you think this is ok?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv you are correct, but I want to find any other solution. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

There're two solutions may meet your requirement:

Solution1:

modify the property in your EmployeeDetails Model

```
public virtual Employee? Employee { get; set; }
```

Solution2:

disable the null validation in your csproj file as below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    ......
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    ......
  </PropertyGroup>
```