# How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model ？The properties of these object properties also need to be ignored

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

There are object properties on the model，It also needs to be ignored。And The properties of these object properties also need to be ignored,how ?

i find this
[How to configure Swashbuckle to ignore property on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model)

i have tried,but only object properties are ignored,the properties of these object properties is not

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.