Exclude circular references inside Swagger .NET
I have a project that got migrated to .NET 8 recently and I've found that the build pipeline's terraform scripts are unable to generate the Swagger JSON, thus unable to add it to our APIM.
What I've found is that this is caused by circular references.
I tried recreating the same issue inside a dummy project to see whether some dependencies are causing this issue, but this seems like a generic issue, so the use case and the question is the same. A simple fix would be to remove the circular references themselves from the classes, however this is not really an option in our use case. One thing I've seen work is using System.Text.Json and using the [JsonIgnore] annotation on the property, however the team is steering away from using it and favoring Newtonsoft.Json - which does not work.
Is there any other generic way to exclude circular references when generating the JSON schema for swagger?
Do note that swagger generates the schema just fine - however the circular references are the culprit as to why I can't get the swagger up for the service.
Simple example:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CircularReferenceFix;

public class WeatherForecast
{
public DateOnly Date { get; set; }

public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

public string? Summary { get; set; }

// Include Circular reference to test
[JsonIgnore]
public WeatherForecast NextForecast { get; set; }
}

// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005730/how-to-configure-swashbuckle-to-ignore-property-on-model See the different implemented filters there. There is a likelyhood that for the "circular" problem some or all filters shown are executed to late so presumably you need to experiment a bit with those.

Adding the following in your Program.cs will switch to Newtonsoft, and includes the setting to ignore circular references
// swithces serializer from System.Text.Json to Newtonsoft 
// this will not work if switching from MVC/Controllers to Minimal API 
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    // add additional serializer settings
});

// switches Swagger to use Newtonsoft
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();

Additional project references needed:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="8.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" Version="6.5.0" />

See the following guides for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support-2
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft
